# Drupal encoding and node insert

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, character-encoding, drupal-6

I have a CCK type for storing mentions (Social Media search mentions). Some of the mentions I believe are ASCII (My knowledge of this stuff is little).

I retrieve data from API's, which I then using node_save to save to Drupal.

My question is, what should I use to safely convert whatever I am getting into a format Drupal and MySQL are happy with?

The particular db_query error I get is unhelpfull "Warning in test1\includes\common.inc on line 3538". Nice. I have traced it to be encoding, as I used the following code to make the input safe, but it is not working with all input.

```
$node->title = htmlentities($item['title'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

It worked well for some ASCII characters, like those square ones [] etc, but not for this "行けなくてもずっとユーミンは聴きつづけます".

I'm really stuck. :(

UPDATE: The EXACT error I get from PHP is "Warning in D:\sites\test1\includes\common.inc on line 3538", and the line reads "if (db_query($query, $values)) {".

UPDATE 2: I've confirmed that the encoding of the data I am receiving is UTF8. This really doesn't make sense now, and I've confirmed that the collation in the db is utf8_general_ci.

UPDATE 3: One of the title's is: How Much Does A Facebook Fan Cost?� $1.07

The output of:

> var_export(array_map('ord', str_split($node->title))

gave me the character 160 for the funny question mark (which is a square like [] in eclipse).

UPDATE 4: MySQL version is 5.1.41, and the collation on the columns is utf8_general_ci.

UPDATE 5: I managed to get Drupal to print the query with db_queryd. Funny thing is now I get the exact error message and not "Warning in", but Drupal still doesn't have this error in the log! WTF. So the exact sql is:

```
INSERT INTO node (vid, type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, moderate, sticky, tnid, translate) VALUES (0, 'sm_mention', '', 'How Much Does A Facebook Fan Cost?� $1.07 (Geoffrey A. Fowler/Digits)', 1, 1, 1298395302, 1298395302, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

And the error given is: Incorrect string value: '\xA0 $1.0...' for column 'title' at row 1

This honestly sounds like something doesn't like extended ascii characters.

UPDATE 6:

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE node: 

   CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `moderate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tnid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `translate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
  KEY `node_created` (`created`),
  KEY `node_moderate` (`moderate`),
  KEY `node_promote_status` (`promote`,`status`),
  KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
  KEY `node_title_type` (`title`,`type`(4)),
  KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
  KEY `translate` (`translate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1700 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: In order to answer this question you need to post the exact error and also whatever is on line 3538 'cos it's hard to guess... it's somewhere in drupal_write_record, isn't it.

Comment: yeah... that is the EXACT error. I was shocked myself. The line on 3538 reads: if (db_query($query, $values)) {

Comment: `file_put_contents('/tmp/log', var_export(array_map('ord', str_split($node->title)), TRUE));` or something like that. copy-paste is very unlikely to work... having the characters themselves would help. Then we can begin to look for the problem. Also give us MySQL version and check your tables and columns to have some utf8 collation.

Comment: Do you have a virtual machine with ubuntu, or some other modern Linux version around for testing? I have seen similar issues arraise on windows machines several times. Without finding a proper solution, to be fair; the only solution then being "probably some windows incompatability, but we deploy on Linux, so let's not spend too much time debugging MS windows" :)

Comment: hehe. I'd love to but I am all windows, no ubuntu to be found in my world.

Comment: Could you please enable the general log (`SET GLOBAL general_log = 1`) and post the exact query which gets sent to the server?

Comment: I've set general log on, but nothing is getting logged. :(

Comment: @lordg: could you please output the value of `$query` right before the line it emits the warning? Also, when responding to a user (say, me), please start your comment with @nickname, like on twitter, so that I can see your response in my inbox. Thanks!

Comment: @Quassnoi: This is the value of query as db_query receives it: INSERT INTO {node} (vid, type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, moderate, sticky, tnid, translate) VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s', %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d)

Comment: @Quassnoi: And this is the exact query mysql_query is given (except the <?> is a [], which I believe is ascii extended 160): INSERT INTO node (vid, type, language, title, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, moderate, sticky, tnid, translate) VALUES (0, 'sm_mention', '', 'How Much Does A Facebook Fan Cost?� $1.07 (Geoffrey A. Fowler/Digits)', 1, 1, 1298401475, 1298401475, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: @lordg: could you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE node`?

Comment: @Quassnoi: ok, pasted a copy in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\xA0` is not a valid start of a `UTF8` sequence.

The character known as `NO-BREAK SPACE` having the `Unicode` codepoint `0x00A0` should be encoded as `0xC2A0` in `UTF8`.

Thus said, your input string is broken, it's not a valid `UTF8`.

Comment: @Quassnoi the input string only has a Chr(160). There is no multi-byte encoding in it (or should I say, it is UTF8, but only contains ASCII). The '\xA0' appears in the error message upon calling mysql_query.

Comment: @IanC: `\xA0` is `160` in decimal. This is not a valid `UTF8`.

Comment: @Quassnoi So anything that is in the extended ASCII range needs to be encoded for UTF8 representation? "A" (65) can be 1 char, but Chr(160) needs to be 2? I don't program in PHP. I am familiar with "&H" and "0x" meaning "hex", but I haven't seen "\x". This also is a std. way of indicating hex?

Comment: @IanC: yes, everything after `128` takes more than one byte. The error message with `\x` is produced by `MySQL`, not `PHP`. Don't know whether it is standard or not.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thanks for your input! I took what you said and the cleaned the input using http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php to UTF8//TRANSLIT. Now it works without errors! hoooraaay!

Comment: @Quassnoi Got it re. UTF. I didn't realize that MySQL checks the input for validity. I was expecting more of a binary approach of "who cares". @LordG said he got the query to execute ok directly inside MySQL. Odd.

Comment: @IanC: `MySQL` will still insert the node. This error is actually a warning. Most probably it's `Drupal` who sees the error and rolls back the insert.