# Node insert continues to call nodeapi even if query failed

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a custom nodapi function for performing additional opporations when a type of content type is inserted. However, I've had the following error occur "Warning in test1\includes\common.inc on line 3538.". I've tracked this down several times to being an encoding issue, and I'm not sure how to resolve that though.

However, what I don't get is even though the query fails, nodeapi still gets called and I get a blank nid. This also causes other inserts to fail because nid and vid are 0 or null.

I understand that the causing issue is the encoding, but I don't understand why Drupal still runs nodeapi if the node insert (I believe) is failing and no nid or vid is produced.

Any help would be appreciated.

Greg.

Comment: I think that is irrelevant to the issue. Drupal should not be calling hook_nodeapi at all if the node insert failed. Unless this is by design, and I need to check for the presence of nid, but even with that, if a node update fails on node_save, how does nodeapi know?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`node_save`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6). Drupal runs the queries but doesn't check the result of the queries. So `hook_nodeapi` regardless of the node is actually saved in the database.

Drupal could check the result of the query, but doing so would bring to much overhead, to a problem that only could be caused by incorrect database setup. Drupal requires a proper database setup, like it requires a webserver and PHP. It shouldn't be Drupal's job to check that these systems function properly.

Comment: You make it sound as if it is by design that Drupal offers no transactions in its hooks. It is correct that Drupal will continue calling hooks, even if one failed. But that is more due to "we never thought of that", then that it was by choice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I hardly believe that is added over head at all when drupal_write_record itself returns a result. IMHO Drupal should never continue the nodeapi hook calls when the node query itself fails.

Comment: @lordg: The best option is on IMO to call the hook regardless, since it would allow modules to clean up what they did in presave, on insert failure. You can check for the presence of the nid if you want/need that check. Regardless this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @berkes: It may be by chance or it may be well thought of. Only those that actually wrote the code knows. My point is that it actually is the best behavior all things considered. That is at least how I think about it.

Comment: @googletorp: valid point regarding the presave. This does however leave us with a problem in node updates then. The best solution would be for the node to have an added property that tells nodeapi funcs the result so they can decide completely for themselves.

Comment: Well, I was there when we discussed this back in Drupal 3.something and again in 4.something. And again in 5. Only in Drupa-6 an attempt at making the return-values of hooks more consistent. See the "drupal_write_record", which does return the inserted record (without added overhead). Its just that not everywhere drupal_write_record is used and that even where it is, the return-values are often not mitigated upstream.

Comment: @berkes or @googletorp: what do you think is causing failure on the insert as I believe it is encoding related. Would you mind commenting on this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028316/drupal-encoding-and-node-insert.